# How to resizing svg images for a print preview only?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, printing

Right now I have some d3 graphs that on the page that listen to the screen resize event and can be enlarged quite large. However when a user goes to print them they are too big for the printed page. If I limit the size of the svg's then if the screen is resized really wide then they wont scale.

**In other words I need my svg's to be a certain size in the print preview yet still scale in the browser view port. How could one accomplish this?**

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use media queries to scale the graphs.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

For example:

```
@media print { 
    svg {
        width: 3in;
    }
}
```

Comment: For print, inches (in) or centimeters (cm) are probably better units to use.